# Visual Basic 2010 - How to append certain areas of a text document using data collected in a form

Tags: vb.net

I routinely reuse code for Cisco routers / switches and some web accelerators. I usually have to open the text document, edit a few IPs, host names, license keys etc. The remaining 98% of the text document stays the same. My end goal is to develop a program in Visual Basic (or whatever anyone can recommend would accomplish this easier) that will allow me to generate a text document with their data in the right place.

I have been able to develop a GUI form, it looks exactly how I want. I have a box to enter their hostname, classification, IP address etc; now, when I press the "Generate" button at the bottom, I want a new text document on the desktop. When you open the txt, all of their data has been appended to the document in the exact places it should be and all of my original text is still there, just the specific parts have been changed.

I've got the gui, just dont know where to add my existing code and how to make the different objects change their respective parts.

Hopefully this all makes sense. Thank you in advance, I really appreciate it.

Josh

Comment: Firstly, why is this question tagged with vb.net and visual c++?  Which one do you want to write the code in?

Comment: Secondly, what have you tried already and where did it fail?  If you haven't tried anything then posting a question here is premature.  This site is about fixing specific problems, not teaching you the basics of programming.  There is a ton of information on the web already about string manipulation and writing to text files.

Comment: I only meant the tag to be visual basic, sorry. 

Clearly I'm in the wrong place. Figured someone could throw me a bone on an article that would explain how to do this.

Comment: What you could do is to create your template document with unique place holders that you can do a search on and replace them with the proper values.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I was looking for.

Thank you for taking the time to answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty example of my comment, using `String.Replace` to replace the placeholders. See if this helps you.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub generate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles generate.Click
        Dim temp As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\temp\template.txt")
        temp = temp.Replace("##placeHolder1##", TextBox1.Text) _
                   .Replace("##placeHolder2##", TextBox2.Text) _
                   .Replace("##placeHolder3##", TextBox3.Text)
        File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\custom.txt", temp)
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

To answer your question about embedding the file into the application. Yes it is possible just go to Project --> Properties --> Resources  click Add Resource and select Add Existing File (*Just make sure that your template has a .txt file extension, you can rename it to what you want when you save the file*), then when you  go to your solution explorer you will see a directory called Resources with template.txt in it. right click on it and select properties then select the Build Action Property to Embedded Resource this will embed the file into the program.  You will then be able to access the template like this.

```
Dim temp As String = My.Resources.template
```

[image]

Comment: If I had more rep on StackOverflow I'd up-vote this a million times. This did EXACTLY what I was trying to do. Now I have a general idea of what I need to complete this form. You sir, are the man. Is there anyway I can have my template built into the application, just hidden somewhere, so that way they can input their required fields and it will put that custom.txt on the desktop without the need for it to be in C:\\temp first. Regardless, you got it to work and for that I thank you- –

Comment: I was able to embed my stock template using the instructions you gave me. It is now a 100% mobile application and does exactly what I want.

I cannot thank you enough again Mark.