# Editing parts of document in WPF to print

Tags: c#, wpf, document, editing, xps

I am making WPF application in C#.

I want to make users to fill up some fields in program and after clicking *Save* it will save document (XPS or PDF) from template with filled fields.

I started learning Net and C# about 2 weeks ago and don't know what is the best way in this application to make a filled document from template and user input.

Comment: I answered a similar question for vb.net the principle should be the same. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25965669/479512

Answer (score 1):

You can use Report Viewer Control for that.  It will allow you to create a template in .rdlc format and then fill in parameters during run-time.
[Check out official page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx)